# HTML, responsive layout, and a specific height for high res that scales with lower

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, scaling

So the subject is a bit lengthy.  Anyway, what I'm basically doing is trying to get a unit be a specific height (366px to be exact), but I want that height to scale DOWN if the resolution drops, thus the "min-height: 366px" is naturally out because of that.

I did come up with a rather crummy solution where I inserted an image that's that height, but the image itself is 366 pixels tall and 100% transparent.  That was the only way I could really get the container be the right height.

I need this height because the container will then contain more images within it that scale.  These images are absolutely positioned within the container and are on top of my invisible image.

So is there any way to have a "min-width" that then scales as size goes down or am I out of luck?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you mean by **"resolution drops"**? Do you mean viewport shrinks? Do you have any code? It's really  hard to unerstand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Em.... what about max-width 366px? that **should** work and.. did You use  (it is probably not same as this)